# Searching for a expression of a specific cost function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I am looking for a function $f(x)$ where

- $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ for $x\rightarrow0$
- $f(x)=0$ for $x=1$
- $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$
- only extrempoint (minimum obviously) is at $x=1$
- $f$ is completely differentiable everywhere for $x>0$

I am sure there is a standard way to express a function like that with the Euler constant.

I want to use the function as a cost function for artificial life objects to keep a distance of 1. It should be infinitely costly for two objects to be at the same position and also to move far away from each other.

Comment: $f(x) = e^x/x$ might work if you scale it and subtract the right constant.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Yes, very nice indeed. That satisfies my conditions. Maybe we find something even more elegant without the constant?

Comment: @EthanBolker: How did you come up with that? It does not seem obvious to me that you would get the minimum at $x=1$.

Comment: I didn't know that's where the minimum would be, but I was pretty sure there was a unique minimum, so you'd be able to replace $x$ by $cx$ if necessary. Turned out not to be necessary. $(x  + 1/x)/2$ might work too.